# Color in Arabtext

Tags: color, arabic, arabtex

i have this usepackage, and i'm asking how to write for example [1] in red ?

```
\documentclass[leqn, dvips]{arabart}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{arabtex}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{fancybox}

\usepackage{arqam}

\novocalize \ligsfalse \setarab

\usepackage{fancyhdr}%

\textwidth=18truecm \textheight=26truecm %20.1truecm pour safril2.tex
\hoffset=-4truecm %mmr al-`Ady \voffset=-3.5truecm \ligsfalse
\mathchardef\cap="225C \arabfootnotes \renewcommand{\l}{\mathscr{L}}
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\kern 2pt \newcommand{\supp}{{\rm
supp}\;}

 \hfill\rule[2pt]{7truecm}{0.4pt} }

\newcount\adad \adad=0%134 
\newcommand{\raqm}{\global\advance\adad by
1{\number\adad}}
\newcommand{\tmryn}{\begin{arabtext} $
\shadowbox{\RL{ \bf .hl Alms-'lT}} $ %
\noindent%
}


\begin{document}

\textcolor{red}{[1]}

\end{document}

\end{arabtext}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: your code is working fine, except the missing packge "arqam"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had specified `dvips` so forcing `latex+dvips` if you delete that option then it would work with pdflatex as well (I commented out one package I didn't have)

[image]

```
\documentclass[leqn]{arabart}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{arabtex}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{fancybox}

%\usepackage{arqam}

\novocalize \ligsfalse \setarab

\usepackage{fancyhdr}%

\textwidth=18truecm \textheight=26truecm %20.1truecm pour safril2.tex
\hoffset=-4truecm %mmr al-`Ady \voffset=-3.5truecm \ligsfalse
\mathchardef\cap="225C \arabfootnotes \renewcommand{\l}{\mathscr{L}}
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{\kern 2pt \newcommand{\supp}{{\rm
supp}\;}

 \hfill\rule[2pt]{7truecm}{0.4pt} }

\newcount\adad \adad=0%134 
\newcommand{\raqm}{\global\advance\adad by
1{\number\adad}} \newcommand{\tmryn}{\begin{arabtext} $
\shadowbox{\RL{ \bf .hl Alms-'lT}} $ %\noindent% 
}


\begin{document}

\textcolor{red}{[1]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Now I lost the numerotation of page's how to do? Please

Comment: @Vrouvrou that seems to be an unrelated question? best make a small example and ask as a new question. I have no idea about this class and what page styles it uses by default